# handle parts of string in preg_replace_callback differently

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I got a string in which I replace all occurrences of `[CODE]...[/CODE]`. With `preg_replace_callback` can I call a function which handles the content of those tags. But how can I manipulate all string which are around those occurrences?

Example:

```
$str = "Hello, I am a string with [CODE]some code[/CODE] in it";
```

Now, with `preg_replace_callback` I manipulate the content of `[CODE]`, in this case `some code`.  But I'd like for all other text in this string, so `Hello, I am a string with` and `in it` to do something different. How could I do this the best way?

Thank you for you help!

Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be simpler if I could see the regex, but the gist is that I think you want capture groups.

You should be able to access those regions separately by placing them into parenthesis-wrapped groups.  Each  section will be available to your callback.  So (crudely) something like `/(.*)(\[CODE\].*\[/CODE\])(.*)/` should pass an array of matches to your callback

Comment: Regex should be `/(.*)(\[CODE\].*\[\/CODE\])(.*)/` should it not? `\[CODE\]` accepts `[CODE]` while the second CODE is `[/CODE]`

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin yeah, thanks. I was hoping just the capture group arrays would be a nudge in the right direction, but wrong regex is confusing.  I'll fix it.